# ¿Como puedo insertar el nombre del usuario que accedio a mi BD SQL Server en una tabla?

Tags: sql

Me gustaria saber si puedo insertar el nombre del usuario que accedió a mi tabla, es decir, su nombre de login de esa forma podría crear una bitacora  simple.

Conozco que para insertar la fecha es con `getdate()` y me gustaria saber si existe algo similar para el usuario.

La herramienta que utilizo es SQL Server.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan suministrar.

Comment: [Mira aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), quizá te podría servir.

Comment: Puedes usar:
select suser_sname();